# Join/merge a feature class to a standalone table and have the output be a feature class

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a standalone table with ~100,000 rows and a line feature class of ~700 rows (roads) that share a common attribute (road_name). I want to append the fields of the feature class to the standalone table and have that read as a feature class. I want this new feature class to display the ~700 roads but I want the new attribute table to contain the ~100,000 rows from the standalone table. I have tried various 'Joins' but to no avail. Would a Merge be appropriate?

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: A Merge is not going to help here.

Comment: This is trivial (and somewhat sluggish) with a view in a database, and unworkably slow in most any other format. Please [Edit] the Question to provide details on the software and format in use.

Comment: What sort of features to do you want to create for the thousands of rows in the table that do not have related features in the feature class?  Do you want them to have NULL geometry?  They are not suitable to be in a feature class.  You may need to re-think your strategy, as having a feature class (mostly) full of features with NULL geometry doesn't make much sense.  There is most likely a much better way to achieve what you are aiming for.  Why do you want to do this?  What is the purpose of trying to do this?  (Please edit and update your question with any further information.)